# Cannot search taxonomy tags and terms?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have two drupal sites running locally on my computer. When i try to test the search of two sites, the other works fine, the other is not. I tried to search taxonomy terms and tags but it yielded no results. I don't know what the problem is, please comment or any advise?

Comment: have you tried to re-index search?

Comment: What do you mean by "search taxonomy terms and tags"? Are you trying to limit your search just to terms? Have you cleared cache and run cron?

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/62557/how-to-show-taxonomy-terms-and-tags