# How to show taxonomy terms and tags?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes

i have two separate contents in two different content type. The other one is in the basic page, other one is in the content type i made(regional malls). The taxonomy terms or tags is showing in basic page when i publish but my problem is in the regional malls content, when i published, taxonomy terms or tags does not show up, any ideas why is this happening?or advise how to overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create separate .tpl for content types and then put the code to print taxonomy term

```
<?php if($node->field_category): ?>
<div class = "top_tag">
  <?php print $node->field_category['und'][0]['taxonomy_term']->name;?>
</div>
<?php endif;?>
```

put this code in template.tpl.php

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$vars) { // replace mytheme with your theme name
  if (isset($vars['node']->type)) {
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__' . $vars['node']->type;
  }
}
```

hope it helps you!

Comment: how can i create this?can u teach me ho to do this? im only beeginner..